# Magento - half page breaking

Tags: php, javascript, magento

i am stuck with an issue on magento store. half of page display and then it breaks. 
here is my page.

http://www.statecertification.com/regshop/class-locator.html

if you look page source, this is code where it breaks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var marker, i;
        var map;
        var store_locations = <?php echo json_encode($Stores); ?>;
```

can any one look into , same page is working on other servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of magnento and php are you using because it definitely a php error? json_encode require php >= 5.2.0

Also try

```
var store_locations = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($Stores);?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable Developer Mode and set your index.php to display errors.

Around lines 75-79:

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will enable it - make sure you restore it when you are done though.

Also check in `/var/log` plus your Apache logs folder to find out exactly why it's breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose in single quotes:

```
var store_locations = '<?php echo json_encode($Stores); ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the echo:

```
 var store_locations = <?= json_encode($Stores); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

No quote needed as it's JSON ..

```
var test = {'var1':1, 'var2':2};
//this is totally OK and must not be enclosed bu quotes (a JSON object is not a string!)
```

By the way it's not a javascript issue, but a PHP hidden Fatal error. (the HTML is truncated, with or without quotes..)

To see what happened, you need to activate error display :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors' 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Looking at your source, there can be 2 problems :

- json_encode function is missing (what is your PHP version ?)
- $Stores variable is undefined or not a STRING

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion, the problem is not in the quotes and etc.

I bet, that the variable $Stores, doesn't exist.

The author also can do the following actions to discover the problem:

In index.php use  ini_set('display_errors', '1'); instead of #ini_set('display_errors', '1');
This will show you, what is the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact situation today. Homepage loaded till half and then breaks, no footer, etc. I already had ioncube loader installed and that was not the issue. In my case it turned out to be a file midcolumn.phtml from my theme folder /app/design/frontend/yourthemehere/default/template/page/html/midcolumn.phtml because I edited this file yesterday and when I restored the original file the homepage worked again just fine.
This my not be your case though. I suggest turning magento debug by uncommenting line in your index.php file

## ini_set('display_errors', 1);

*(remove # and put it back when your done)